# How to apply affine transform to part of the image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

There is an image with 3 anchor points (black rectangle). An affine transformation can be generated from these points.

It's easy to transform the whole image with the generated matrix, but if I want to transform a part of the image (green rectangle), how to do it?

The only way I know is to extend the green rectangle to full size image, transform, then crop it again.

[image]

---

Update to make it more clear.
If I have the image above and a transformer, the transformed image is like:
[image: transformed]

Because the image is big and takes long time to complete the transformation, so I only want to transform part of the image (the green rectangle)

what I expect is crop the green rectangle and perform some transformation to it, to get the same result.
[image: part of image]
[image: part of image transformed]

Comment: what exactly to you want to achieve? You can transform the whole image and from the result crop the region where your green rectangle was. To save speed you could also limit the result space, but that's a bit complicated, so maybe tell why you want to transform only the part. Is it for speed or for content or...?

Comment: @Lamp Please show the code that transforms and crop, or at least post the transformation matrix, and an example that shows the desired output. It's hard to find the context between the 3 anchor points and the green rectangle. Transforming the green rectangle is not well defined (we have to know the transformation matrix and the desired size or the output image).

Comment: @Micka try to speed up, the green rectangle is interested are, but cannot find enough anchor points in it.

Comment: @Rotem If there is no known algorithms, maybe have to transform the whole image. the transformation matrix is some small offset combine with small rotation.

Comment: @Lamp Please update your question. Please read my previous comment again. "Transforming the green rectangle is not well defined", and I don't like guessing...

Comment: 1. transform the 4 corners of your green rectangle to the dst image positions and compute their bounding rectangle 2. move the transformation ( H2= T * H ) so that the top left corner of the bounding rect is at (0,0) 3. warp the image with H2 to a destination image size equal to the bounding rect size. 4. now you have the green rectangle  (and their bounding rect) warped. Regard that you can only warp rectangular destination regions, so if your greent rect differs strongly from the bounding rectangle (warped), you will need a mask to know which dst pixels really are from the green rectangle.

Comment: @Lamp I see that you didn't add a Python tag. I hope that you indented to get the solution in Python. (Note that I still had to assume that you know the transformation of the ROI by itself as a "small image", because you didn't post the transformation  matrix). Please check my answer.

Comment: @Lamp I updated my answer with a new example that assumes that the center of the ROI should be the center of the destination "small image" (output of the warp). I think it better fits your intentions.

Comment: @Lamp Can you please respond my answer? I would like to know if my answer is correct or not. In case my answer doesn't answer your question, and you still like to have an answer, please post a reproducible code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically we may chain the transformation matrix of a "ROI sized image" with translation matrix that "shifts" the ROI to the top-left corner of the "large image".

Assume we have an image in the size of the ROI (name it `roi`):

[image]

Assume we know the transformation matrix `M` for that given ROI image:

```python
M = np.array([[ 1.03366188, 0.37622216,  50],
              [-0.37622216, 1.03366188, 100]])
```

---

Here is an example for computing the transformation matrix `M`:

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('input_image.png');

x0, y0 = 770, 491  # Top left corner of the ROI in the image.
roi = img[y0:685, x0:1129, :]
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((roi.shape[1]/2, roi.shape[0]/2), 20, 1.1)  # Rotation and scale
M[0:2, 2] = (50, 100)  # Add translation
print(M)
```

---

Building transformation matrix be applied on the "large image" with the given ROI:

- Prepare transformation matrix that applies translation.
  The translation "shifts" each pixel in the "large image" to bring the ROI to the top-left corner of the image.
  Translation matrix:

```python
    T = np.array([[1, 0, -x0],
                  [0, 1, -y0],
                  [0, 0,  1]])
```

- Add row [0, 0, 1] to the bottom of `M`.
  OpenCV convention for affine transformation is omitting the bottom row that equals `[0, 0, 1]`.
  We have to add the omitted row for making M size 3x3.

```python
    M = np.vstack((M, np.array([0, 0, 1])))
```

- Chain transformation - multiply `M` by the translation matrix `T`:

```python
    roiM = M @ T
```

- Remove the last row of `roiM` for matching OpenCV 2x3 affine transformation conventions:

```python
    roiM = roiM[0:2, :]
```

- Apply `warpAffine` to the "large image" with `roiM` transformation matrix:

```python
    rotated_roi = cv2.warpAffine(img, roiM, (dst_width, dst_height))
```

---

For testing, we may apply `warpAffine` to `roi` with matrix `M`:

```python
rotated_roi_ref = cv2.warpAffine(roi, M, (dst_width, dst_height))
```

---

Code sample:

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('input_image.png');

x0, y0 = 770, 491    # Top left corner of the ROI in the image.
#roi = img[y0:685, x0:1129, :]
#M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((roi.shape[1]/2, roi.shape[0]/2), 20, 1.1)  # Rotation and scale
#M[0:2, 2] = (50, 100)  # Add translation
#print(M)

M = np.array([[ 1.03366188, 0.37622216,  50],
              [-0.37622216, 1.03366188, 100]])

dst_width = 538  # int(roi.shape[1]*1.5)
dst_height = 291  # int(roi.shape[0]*1.5)

# Translation matrix - "shifts" the ROI to the top-left corner of img
T = np.array([[1, 0, -x0],
              [0, 1, -y0],
              [0, 0,  1]])

M = np.vstack((M, np.array([0, 0, 1])))  # Add row [0, 0, 1] to the bottom of M (we need M to be 3x3 before matrix multiplication).

roiM = M @ T  # Chain transformations - each source pixel is translated by x=-770 and y=-491 and warped with M after the translation.
roiM = roiM[0:2, :]  # Keep only the two upper rows (warpAffine input is 2x3 matrix).

rotated_roi = cv2.warpAffine(img, roiM, (dst_width, dst_height))


# Reference for testing: apply warp to roi
################################################################################
roi = img[y0:685, x0:1129, :]
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((roi.shape[1]/2, roi.shape[0]/2), 20, 1.1)  # Rotation and scale
M[0:2, 2] = (50, 100)  # Add translation
rotated_roi_ref = cv2.warpAffine(roi, M, (dst_width, dst_height))
################################################################################


# Show output images for testing:
#cv2.imshow('roi', roi)
cv2.imshow('rotated_roi', rotated_roi)
cv2.imshow('rotated_roi_ref', rotated_roi_ref)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

`rotated_roi`:
[image]

`rotated_roi_ref` (reference for testing):
[image]

---

### Update:

Different assumptions:

- Assume the transformation matrix of the "large image" is given.
- Assume we want the center of the ROI is the "large image" to be transformed to the center of the desired destination image.

Code sample (please read the comments):

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('input_image.png');

x0, y0 = 770, 491    # Top left corner of the ROI in the image.
x1, y1 = 1128, 684   # Bottom left corner of the ROI

# Size of destination image (output of Warp)
dst_width = 538
dst_height = 291

# Assume the following transformation matrix M is given:
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((img.shape[1]/2, img.shape[0]/2), 15, 1.05)  # Transformation matrix that applies the "large image"

# Center coordinate of the ROI:
roi_cx = (x1 + x0) / 2
roi_cy = (y1 + y0) / 2

# Transform the center coordinate of the ROI and get the center coordinate after the transformation (after the transformation of the "large image").
transformed_roi_cx, transformed_roi_cy = cv2.transform(np.array([[[roi_cx, roi_cy]]], np.float64), M)[0][0]

# Center coordinate of the destination image (output of Warp).
dst_cx = (dst_width - 1) / 2
dst_cy = (dst_height - 1) / 2

# Compute the horizontal and vertical translation - how much to shift the center after the "original warp".
tx = dst_cx - transformed_roi_cx
ty = dst_cy - transformed_roi_cy

# Translation matrix:
T = np.array([[1, 0, tx],
              [0, 1, ty],
              [0, 0, 1]])

M = np.vstack((M, np.array([0, 0, 1])))  # Add row [0, 0, 1] to the bottom of M (we need M to be 3x3 before matrix multiplication).

# T is multiplied from the left side - assume warp with M and than "shift" (translation comes after the warp).
roiM = T @ M  # Chain transformations
roiM = roiM[0:2, :]  # Keep only the two upper rows (warpAffine input is 2x3 matrix).

rotated_roi = cv2.warpAffine(img, roiM, (dst_width, dst_height))

cv2.imwrite('rotated_roi.png', rotated_roi)  # Save for testing.
```

---

`rotated_roi`:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Rotem, from the last step, cv2.warpAffine still takes the large image (img) as input. Is it possible to pass the roi image?

Comment: Sure, it is possible to pass a slice (NumPy slice is the equivalent to ROI in OpenCV). We can also "deep" copy the ROI to other NumPy array, but it's a waisted copy. Why do you want to pass the ROI? Please note that the execution time of `warpAffine` is determined by the resolution of the output (it's not going to run faster if we pass the ROI).

Comment: I thought warpAffine process the whole input image, so pass the ROI could make it faster, if only depends on the output, then the answer it good enough.

Comment: The way the algorithm works, is scanning the destination image (say "small image"), for each destination pixel, 4 pixels are read from the source image (say "large image") for linear interpolation. Larger source image may affect performance due to cache misses (due to less temporal locality). NumPy slice is just a view of the ROI, so it's not going to help with cache misses. Copy the ROI is going to take more time than the cache misses in most cases. You may do some benchmarking, just in case. Note: In case large image is in the CPU and warp is going to be in the GPU we better copy the ROI.

Answer (score 2):

Create an image that extracts only the interest rectangular region.

The transformation between pixel positions in this ROI image and pixel positions in the original image is a simple translation.

So, add the translation for this coordinate transformation to the affine transformation and apply it to the ROI image.
Here, the size of the transformed image buffer is the size of the original image.

---

e.g. consider about the warp from original point to result point.

`Result_Position = AffineTrans( Original_Point )`

If ROI is (Left=100,Top=200, Width=any,Height=any) rectangle in the original image,
Point(0,0) in the extracted ROI image corresponds to (100,200) in the original image.

Since the argument of the function `AffineTrans()` is "Point in the Original Image", to use this function for the ROI image, you have to obtain ther argument value by translating the position in the ROI image to in the Original image.
i.e.

`Result_Position = AffineTrans( Point_in_ROI_Image + (100,200) )`

(Of cause, in real, necessary warp direction is the opposite, but what to do is same.)

Comment: If you think this post is wrong or inadequate, please point it out clearly.

Comment: it solves the translation but not the rotation

Comment: Rotation will be done by your affine transform as is.